# Copy Transpose Loop over multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new at VBA I'm wanting to copy and transpose multiple columns and rows. Bonus if I can get alternating blank columns in between. I can get the first column to move but I'm stuck there. I'm assuming I can make a loop somehow? Here is what I'm trying to do for all data A1 to H12.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Can you show us what you tried by yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub ProcessRange()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, r As Long, c As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 arr = sh.Range("B3:M10").value 'put the range to be processed in an array
 
 ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr) / 2, 1 To UBound(arr, 2) * 2) 'ReDim the array to keep the processing result
 r = r + 1: c = c + 1           'initialize variables (r = rows, c = columns) for the final array
 For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)    'iterate between the processed array columns
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)    'iterate between the processed array rows
        If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
             arrFin(r, c) = arr(i, j)  'extract the cases of odd rows
        Else
            arrFin(r, c + 1) = arr(i, j): r = r + 1 'extract the case of even rows and increment the row
        End If
        If i = UBound(arr) Then r = 1: c = c + 2    'reinitialize the row variable and increment the column one
    Next i
 Next j
 'drop the processed array content at once:
 sh.Range("B17").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).value = arrFin
End Sub
```

I make an exception, supposing that you, being new, do not understand the community spirit and rules and answer a question which cannot prove any effort to solve the problem by your own and show us a piece of code, even a not working one.

Please, learn that and ask questions only in the community spirit.

You must learn that we here only help you **correct** your not working solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't intend to go against the rules, this is my first time posting. I will keep that in mind as I keep learning.